# How to dynamically add bootstrap-wizard and initialize it using an Id generated by server side variable

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm having difficulties initializing a bootstrap-wizard generated dynamically by a partial-view. The partial-view model generates an Id value that I'm saving to  a static variable and I'm accessing this static variable in my ajax done callback and it doesn't update its value. This static variable id value is part of the bootstrap-wizard id.

I have added a service to render partial-view to a string and return the string along with id value as a json object.

```
htmlString = await this.RenderViewToStringAsync("_BlankEmployeeAssignment", new EmployeeAssignmentViewModel(), true);

return Json(new {html = htmlString, id = SettingsHelper.RecordIndex});

or

return Json(new { html = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(htmlString, Formatting.None), id = SettingsHelper.RecordIndex });

or

return Json(new { html = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(htmlString), id = SettingsHelper.RecordIndex });
```

This works but the problem is I cannot render the html as it contains escaped characters that jquery.parseHtml or JSON.parse is unable to parse back to pure html. So I'm using the standard technique as follows but the challenge is getting an updated value of SettingsHelper.RecordIndex even if I use TempData["RecordIndex"] = Model.RecordId;

```
return PartialView("_BlankEmployeeAssignment", new EmployeeAssignmentViewModel());
```

I have an abstract class containing all common properties

```
[BindRequired]
public abstract class AssetAssignmentViewModel
{
   public string RecordId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
   .... other properties
}
```

This class inherits from the abstract class and adds its unique navigation properties

```
public class EmployeeAssignmentViewModel : AssetAssignmentViewModel
{
   ...other unique properties
}
```

I call into this endpoint using ajax

```
[Route("[action]", Name = "BlankEmployeeAssignment"), HttpGet("AddBlankEmployeeAssignment")]
public IActionResult AddBlankEmployeeAssignment()
{
      return PartialView("_BlankEmployeeAssignment", new EmployeeAssignmentViewModel());
}
```

Inside _BlankEmployeeAssignment partial-view i have the following code saving RecordId into either a TempData or static variable

```
@model EmployeeAssignmentViewModel

@{

    ViewData["Icon"] = "fa fa-plus-square-o";

    SettingsHelper.RecordIndex = Model.RecordId;

    TempData["RecordIndex"] = Model.RecordId;
}
```

I make the ajax call here

```
function addDynamicWizard(target, url, doneCallback) {

            jQuery.ajax({
                url: url,
                method: "GET",
                dataType: "html",
                cache: false,
                success: function (html) {

                    html = jQuery(html).hide().fadeIn(1000);

                    jQuery(target).append(html);
                },
                error: ajaxErrorHander
            }).done(doneCallback);

            return false;
        }
```

When the partial-view has been appended to the container, I have a done function callback

```
function ajaxWizardDoneHandler(data)
        {
            pageSetUp();

            var id = "@TempData["RecordIndex"]";

            runBootstrapWizard('#bootstrap-wizard-' + "@SettingsHelper.RecordIndex",
                runWizardFormValidator("#assignmentForm"));
        }
```

Both TempData and static SettingsHelper.RecordIndex are carrying outdated values not the newly generated RecordId created when I called AddBlankEmployeeAssignment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that worked for me: I added an overloaded constructor to my view-model, this constructor parameter is of type `HttpContext`

```
[BindRequired]
public abstract class AssetAssignmentViewModel
{
   public string RecordId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
   .... other properties

   public AssetAssignmentViewModel(HttpContext context)
   {
      if (context != null)
      {
           context.SetCookie("RecordIndex", RecordId, 
           TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
       }
   }
}
```

I also added an extension method

```
public static class CookieHelper
{
    public static void SetCookie(this HttpContext httpContext, string key, string value, 
     TimeSpan expires)
    {
         CookieOptions option = new CookieOptions();

          if (httpContext.Request.Cookies[key] != null)
          {
             httpContext.Response.Cookies.Delete(key);
          }

          option.Expires = DateTime.Now.Add(expires);

          httpContext.Response.Cookies.Append(key, value, option);
     }
}
```

To access/read this cookie on the client-side, I added a JavaScript library called js.cookie.js available here : https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

```
Cookies.get("RecordIndex");
```

I modified my ajax end-point or action-method as follows:

```
[Route("[action]", Name = "BlankEmployeeAssignment"), HttpGet("AddBlankEmployeeAssignment")]
public IActionResult AddBlankEmployeeAssignment()
{
      return PartialView("_BlankEmployeeAssignment", new 
      EmployeeAssignmentViewModel(HttpContext));
}
```

I modified the ajax-done event handler as follows:

```
function ajaxWizardDoneHandler(data)
{
   pageSetUp();

    runBootstrapWizard('#bootstrap-wizard-' + Cookies.get("RecordIndex"),
    runWizardFormValidator("#assignmentForm"));
}
```

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.